# Random Squares next to logo

Tags: html, css

On http://gilkeslawfirm.com, a site me and my husband are working on, there are 2 blue squares to the left of the logo.  What do we need to edit within php or the css style sheet to get rid of those?

Comment: Please include specific code or image

Comment: open site, right click on blue squares, click `inspect element`, and see whats happening(delete full div), see `slider_text_container` `div`

Comment: This worked. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lines number 99 and 100. Remove them.

```
<h2><a></a></h2> 

<p><a></a></p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have two empty tags `<a></a>` on the page in that place. So - just find them and remove. Then those squares gone.